# SQL Server Estimated Execution plan with red dots on Inner Joins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a very slow SQL Server Query, I am inspecting its Execution Plan and I found out a couple of Inner Joins that are marked with a red dot (not a good sign, I believe).

I have never seen such a red dot on any Plan Operator, what does these red dot mean? And possibly any idea or hint on how to manage them?

[image]

Comment: Hover your mouse over those icons and you should be getting an explanation message

Comment: Well, it simply says "warning: no join clause selected", but that's what I need, a cross join. Why the red dots?

Comment: The query optimizer is warning you about a join statement without predicates. Which it (rightfully) sees as bad behaviour. Without the full execution plan, which you can share through here: [pastetheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), and/or actual query itself however, we can't help you further.

Comment: Try using `cross join`, `cross apply`, `outer apply` to see if it affects the warning in the execution plan.